# How to dynamically make properties of a dynamic type optional?

Tags: typescript

I know there is a way to generate a type dynamically: [Typescript dynamically create types based on object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63995567/typescript-dynamically-create-types-based-on-object)

But I can't find a way to make some properties of the dynamically generated type optional.

For example, say I have a object

```
const obj = {
  keyName1: {
     type: 'string',
     required: true
  },
  keyName1: {
     type: 'string',
     required: false
  },
}
```

How do I make a type based on this object? Given that some properties are optional (if required is false).

If I simply have this object:

```
const obj = {
  keyName1: 'string'
}
```

I could make a type with:

```
  type Generate<T> = T;
  type Generated = Generate<typeof myObj>
```

But with optional parameters, I don't know how...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll first need a utility type mapping each type string (eg `'string'`) to its type (`string`).

Then, map the object properties and do `Obj[K]['required'] extends true ?` to conditionally check whether to alternate with `undefined` or not. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68492618) for how to separate out the optional properties from the non-optional properties in the new object.

```
const obj = {
  keyName1: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true
  },
  keyName2: {
    type: 'number',
    required: false
  },
} as const;
type Obj = typeof obj;
type TypesByTypeof = {
    'string': string;
    'number': number;
}

type ObjType = {
  [key in keyof Obj as Obj[key]['required'] extends true ? key : never]: TypesByTypeof[Obj[key]['type']]
} & {
  [key in keyof Obj as Obj[key]['required'] extends false ? key : never]?: TypesByTypeof[Obj[key]['type']]
}
```

Result:

```
type ObjType = {
    readonly keyName1: string;
} & {
    readonly keyName2?: number | undefined;
}
```