# Make field optional depending on its type

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-generics

I have initial type like this:

```js
type A = {
  x: string | null;
  y: number;
  z: boolean | null;
}
```

Is it possible to create Generic TS type to transform type A to type B?
(whenever field contains null type - it should become optional and without null):

```js
type B = {
  x?: string;
  y: number;
  z?: boolean;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can mapped types make properties optional, but only if a condition is met?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68492248/can-mapped-types-make-properties-optional-but-only-if-a-condition-is-met)

Comment: @pilchard I adapted it to my needs, but for "extends null" seems it doesn't work. Don't you know why it happens?
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AhgGwHIFcMYB4AVAPigF4oBvAKCnqgG0BrCEKBFKVkJAMyhEAugC5BLNkKgQAHsAgoAJgGcoKPBigB+bmyhiUEAG4QATjQC+E3gOE0aoSLHjJ0GAIKnTaEMuJlyOgYYAFsEYGIAGmdEVExcfH8yADIoAHo0qABzCGAoVGhHaAB3cIALJBw8tC8fXV8g+gAFGsRMAiaEAGNmKJjXeI0ksgzs3PzDKCKoUuAyqBrvdh5VNFUkFziMe055Uz40LugAURk0ELAMaFp6PiQkMWVgU04sqAAfNQ0AbiCAIxqBhwIT+Zl+Fl+DnAJzOFyuACYKP0tp4ln5TudLhASJCuqgnlAjJgcBAAIxiDFwiCIyg3KB3B5ffCRf6AqCklkWIA

Comment: @eugenedrvnk Use `null extends T[key]` instead. You want to check if `null` is assignable to that type, not if the type is assignable to `null`.

Comment: I would actually do it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJAllm) if you want to remove `null` from the resulting type (which it seems like you do).

Comment: @vr. thanks a lot for your snippet, looks like it's exactly what I need, will take it apart